# My Receiver for SCREEN_OFF doesn't get registered with a Service

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app for a custom lockscreen and I seem to have hit a very annoying speed bump. The thing is, I have a receiver that checks if the screen is off and launches an activity. This works with the IntentFilter (Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) and this cannot be registered in the manifest.I need to keep this alive, even if the app closes, and I have researched and found out that this can be done via a service which I have setup and started via startService(); in one of my main activities. The service is working as I can see it running in the Android settings in my emulator, but the Receiver does not seem to have been registered.

Here is my Service (It is a separate class and not an inner class) and it has been initiated in the manifest:

```
public class LockService extends Service {

private BroadcastReceiver LockReceiver;
public IntentFilter filter;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    LockReceiver = new LockBroadcast();
    registerReceiver(LockReceiver, filter);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(LockReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver (This also is a separate class and not an inner class):

```
public class LockBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent lock = new Intent (context, Lock.class);
    context.startActivity(lock);
}
```

If I register the LockBroadcast in my activity, it works but only if my app is in the foreground.

I would really appreciate any insights to this problem as I have gone through many websites and even posts on StackOverflow and some people have gotten this to work while some have not.

The above code already works for some people but it doesn't work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sincerely thank you for all your time and effort. I was fiddling around my code and rearranged some stuff and got it to work. I shall mark this question as answered so that no one else wastes their time trying to solve my problem. By the way Robin, I took your advise while sifting through my code. Thank you for pointing out something that could be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, please make sure that you haven't left any "unregister receiver" code in your Activity.onDestory()/onStop() method.

Comment: I checked my code and there was an unregister receiver method in my service, but not in any of my activities. I tried removing the unregister receiver method from my service, but it still didn't work.